# Using comment.create listener for fb:comments - fql.query comment in callback

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, dom-events

I inserted the following plugin which works:

```
<fb:comments href="http://www.example.com/" width="580" num_posts="10"></fb:comments>
```

When someone adds a comment, this comment should be posted on another site to a specific post. For this action the user has to be asked for permission.

When someone klicks on the insert comment button, the event listener `FB.Event.subscribe('comment.create' ...`  is fired.

Then if the user didn't give permission to post, a popup opens and asks the user for permission to post to the other page. Then the inserted comment will be pulled from the database (because in the callback of the variable comment_response there is no variable with the message of the comment).

The problem is, that the variable response of the callback of `fql.query` is empty.
I also tried to wait some seconds with timeout.

If I take the output of comment_response.commentID and write it hardcoded outside of other callbacks and the refresh the page, I get a result.

Also if I do a simple request like pulling the name instead of querying the comment, I also get a result. Whats wrong with this code?

```
        <div id="fb-root"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {

        var post_id = 64564346456756;
        var user_id = 12434566778788;

        // init the FB JS SDK
        FB.init({
          appId      : '75645367543465745', // App ID from the App Dashboard
          status     : true, // check the login status upon init?
          cookie     : true, // set sessions cookies to allow your server to access the session?
          xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML tags on this page?
        });

        //post comment
        FB.Event.subscribe('comment.create', function(comment_response){ 
            //console.log( comment_response );

            //try to post on fanpage ... login
            FB.login(function(login_response) {
                 //console.log(response);

                 // user is logged in and granted permissions.
                  if (login_response.authResponse) {

                      //get comment
                      //comment_response.commentID comment_response.href
                      //console.log( comment_response.commentID );

                      FB.api({
                            method: 'fql.query',
                            query: "SELECT text FROM comment WHERE post_fbid = '"+comment_response.commentID+"' AND object_id IN (SELECT comments_fbid FROM link_stat WHERE url='http://www.example.com/')",
                            access_token: login_response.accessToken
                          },
                          function( response ) {

                              //console.log( resp[0].text );
                              console.log(response);


                          });

                  } 
                  else { // User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.

                  }
             }, {scope:'publish_stream, read_stream'});

        });


      };

      // Load the SDK's source Asynchronously
      (function(d, debug){
         var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
         if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
         js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
         js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/de_DE/all" + (debug ? "/debug" : "") + ".js";
         ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
       }(document, /*debug*/ false));

    </script>

    <fb:comments href="http://www.example.com/" width="580" num_posts="10"></fb:comments>
```